# Bigger File Preview Thumbnail Size

Tags: file-uploads, image

Looking for a way to increase the default thumbnail size of an image uploaded via the file uploader in the CMS e.g:

[image]

At this size, it's hard to tell what is in the image itself. Ideally, we should be able to control this thumbnail size and make it bigger so you can see the image clearly from within the entry editor.

Can't seem to find any plugins or information.

Would rather avoid having to hack the core.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this without hacking core, no.

[Assets](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) offers much nicer thumbnails then the native File field (with various size options too).